# Can dark shadow be hurt?

Tags: my-hero-academia

Fumikage Tokoyami's quirk is a shadow who can fight for him. Can this shadow be hurt directly or it's impossible because it's a shadow? Does the manga say something about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as we know, he can only be weakened by light. However, this has never been shown as damage, just his abilities become less powerful and he has less defensive power.

He also can only be outside of Fumikage for so long, after his energy is out he must return.

Comment: I saw him getting frustrated and depressed after being hit by lightning!?